# How to control where the function is run in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I would like to be able to run a function from the directory where it is defined. 
Let's say this is my folder structure:

```
./matlab
./matlab/functions1
./matlab/functions2
```

and I have all directories in my MATLAB path, so I am able to call the functions that are in these directories.

Let's say my function "func" resides in 'matlab/functions1'. My function contains command

```
csvwrite('data.csv', data(:));
```

Now, if I call "func" from ./matlab, 'data.csv' gets created in ./matlab. If I call it from ./matlab/functions2, it will get created in that directory. But I would like for the function to write 'data.csv' always in the directory, where the function is defined (./matlab/functions1), no matter what my current directory is. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[mfilename](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mfilename.html) called from 'inside' a function returns the function path and name.

```
fullPath = mfilename('fullpath');
pathString = fileparts(fullPath);
dataPath = [ pathString filesep 'data.csv'];
csvwrite(dataPath, data(:));
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what @zellus suggested, you can use `functions` to get information on a specific function, regardless of any m file being executed at the same moment. You set the function of interest by giving `functions` the function handle:

```
funInfo = functions(@func);
fullPath = funInfo.file;
```

Comment: Is there a similar function for class files ?